# How is it possible to have a repository with cloners and no visitors?

Tags: github, git-clone, visitor-statistic

I'm not sure if this is apropos, but github is a valid tag, so here goes:

I have several public repositories with low traffic. I am confused how it is possible to have weeks where there are no visitors, and yet the repository has been cloned one or more times.

Seems that to clone it, you'd have to visit, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s easy to construct the clone URL from the repository list on your user page.  Automated processes may very well clone everything to examine the contents later.

Comment: I was able to do so myself after looking into it, so your answer pretty much sums things up.